# How to fix error project offline maps used Nutiteq maps SDK

Tags: android, cartodb, nutiteq, carto-mobile

I'm a newbie in android. I try a project on the used `Nutiteq maps SDK` on Github, but I made some **errors:**

> in class MyMapEventListener error UTFGridRasterTileLayer,class CartoDBTorqueActivity error TorqueTileLayer, class CartoDBVectorTileActivity error CartoCSSStyleSet, class OfflineRoutingActivity error NutiteqOnlineRoutingService.

Comment: I'm afraid the description is too general to give useful answer. Some your code samples would be needed as minimum.

Comment: I import projects into eclipse and build it was like missing library error. You try to download and import the project with the following link:

Comment: https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d-android

Answer (score 1):

From your own comment, I can see you're using Eclipse, however, that is an Android Studio project. The problem could lie there.

Dependencies are downloaded via Gradle, but Eclipse's default is Ant. Have you tried Gradle Eclipse (https://gradle.org/eclipse/) or Android Studio?

Additionally, Nutiteq SDK 3 is old and won't be supported for very long. You should check out the new version, 4.0.0, CartoMobileSDK

- Documentation:
  https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/mobile-sdk/getting-started
- Samples: https://github.com/CartoDB/mobile-android-samples

Comment: Very constructive answer. If anyone comes here, and you're starting a project using Nutiteq old SDK, move to Carto.